# NullPointerException when using BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android

// I learned android studio about BottomNavigationView, but I have a problem like this ... please help me :(

> // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)'
>   on a null object reference// eror logcat

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_filter:
                        selectedFragment = new PesananFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_notifikasi:
                        selectedFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_akun:
                        selectedFragment = new AccountFragment();
                        break;
                }

                assert selectedFragment != null;
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };
```

}

Comment: lol that title question. please rephrase it. and tell us what you want to actually do with the program

Comment: Looks like `bottomNav` is `null`, so `findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)` failed to find it for some reason. Showing the layout file where `bottomNav` is located (supposedly `main_activity.xml`) would be helpful.

Comment: please add your activity layout file, main_activity.xml.

Comment: The view with id `bottom_navigation` does not exist in layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the initial `bottomNav` stationing.
Maybe try to put explicit casting like: 
`BottomNavigationView bottomNav=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);`

If that does not work check the `BottomNavigationView` implementation requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android studio to create a activity that already has a Bottom navigation.